# Book to understand BJT non-linearity

Tags: rf, bjt, high-frequency, non-linear

Can someone please suggest a good book to understand low and high frequency non-linearities like beta, gm, cbe, cbc and rb present in bjt.

Thanks

Comment: Any reputable book would suffice - pick the same book that's used by your peers and school if possible. I personally used Sedra/Smith.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is certainly a matter of opinion. What sings in one's mind varies widely from individual to individual.

That said, there is a singular book on the topic. This is [*Modeling The Bipolar Transistor*](https://www.lulu.com/en/us/shop/ian-getreu/modeling-the-bipolar-transistor/paperback/product-195g6k2j.html?page=1&pageSize=4) from Dr. Ian Getreu. This book was originally written and published internally by Tektronix for customers of their STS systems, as well as for anyone within the company who wanted a copy. (Me, for example.) However, Ian was able to secure the rights to republish it and it is now available via Lulu.

There are several things that are combined, uniquely, to make this a likely candidate. The book starts out with the Level I Ebers-Moll model and moves sequentially from there through Level II and Level III, ending finally on Gummel-Poon. (It also covers some details and the equation of the temperature variation of the saturation current -- not readily found.) It then moves through, model level by model level, all of the model parameters, what they mean, and how to arrange to measure them, experimentally. It then includes a number of Appendices that cover details of further interest, such as how to compare the transport and injection version of the Ebers-Moll model, basewidth modulation analysis, complete derivation of the five charge components in the Gummel-Poon model,  accuracy considerations of basewidth modulation found in EM III and GP, how to derive the small signal models by linearizing EM3 and GP (rarely both are found together), a full cross reference of model parameters between SLIC, SINC, and SPICE as well as references to specific theory papers and measurement details for each, and finally a very full bibliography of the important relevant papers.

(I have no financial interest in this book. Just FYI. But I'm acknowledged in it. I last met Ian at [Barrie Gilbert](https://web.archive.org/web/20200218182255/https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f65e/7d9e6c97a701c97d795cff1d363cb6dcdfc9.pdf)'s funeral. If you buy the book, you are buying Ian some lunch.)